# ¿Cómo comparo elementos de 2 arrays uno a uno?

Tags: javascript, array, google-apps-script

tengo estos dos arrays:

```
var idHlevel = [234567,345678,456789];
var regs = [123456,234567,345678,899065,9876554,6554432]
```

quiero comparar cada elemento en "regs" con cada elemento en "idHlevel".
si por ejemplo el elemento "123456"  de "regs" existe en "idHlevel" hacer algo.

si no existe hacer otra cosa..
¿como lo hago?
no puedo usar la función includes() de Js en Google Apps Script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que dices, `google-apps-script` no soporta `Array.prototype.includes`. Prueba si funciona con `indexOf`

```js
var idHlevel = [234567,345678,456789];
var regs = [123456,234567,345678,899065,9876554,6554432];

regs.forEach(function(reg) {
  if(idHlevel.indexOf(reg)===-1) {
    console.log('El elemento',reg,'NO existe en idHlevel');
  } else {
    console.log('El elemento',reg,'existe en idHlevel');
  }
});
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias @amenadiel